# Universal app : LaunchScreen not respecting interface builder constraint when launching in landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uistoryboard

I have some troubles with the LaunchScreen.storyboard.

My app is a **Universal** App, **default orientation** is **portrait** but landscape is also allowed.

My LaunchScreen is very simple.

A UILabel with 2 constraints :

- Align leading to Safe Area (with constant = 30)
- Top space to Safe Area (with constant = 30)

[image]

When I check my LaunchScreen inside XCode with simulated traits (iPhone XR, iPad, Landscape, Portrait…) everything looks fine.

When I launch the app in **portrait orientation** everything looks **fine**.

Then I turn the simulator (or real device) to **landscape** and re-run the app.

This time the **UILabel doesn't respect it's constraints**. The label is touching the black notch and the top space seems twice the defined size.

[image]

Do you have the same problem ? How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Apple describes this in their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) as follows:

> At launch time, apps should always set up their interface in a portrait orientation. After the application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method returns, the app uses the view controller rotation mechanism described above to rotate the views to the appropriate orientation prior to showing the window.

So I believe the behaviour you're after isn't particularly supported by Apple I'm afraid. As a side note, I'm not entirely sure how they support it on iPads.

Comment: I think you are right, but it's really surprising that we can do everything in LaunchScreen.storyboard but constraints are not applied correctly at launch :/

Comment: I totally agree. Best thing would be to request a feature to Apple that allows this behaviour I'm afraid. A simple solution for your problem might be to try center the label instead, but I'm not sure if that'll work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Apply constraints to your `UILabel` as per my below screenshot :-

[image]

Also, in your project **Target** set **Deployment Info** :-

[image]

If you want to change `UILabel` frame, then ask me.